# Javascript one script on all classes on a page

Tags: javascript

For some reason I am not able to get this working without copy-pasting the code several times and just changing the name of the class.

What I want is that this works for all the classes on the same page but of course not all of them at the same time, it should only work on the current hover.

I know it's possible but I can't seem to be able to get it to work.

So I want this code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("div.hover").mouseover(function ()
  {
    $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
    $("div.overlay").css('visibility','visible');
    $("div.overlay").css('display','block');

  });
  $("div.hover").mouseout(function ()
  {
    $(this).css('cursor', 'default');
    $("div.overlay").css('visibility','hidden');
    $("div.overlay").css('display','none');
  });
});
```

To work on all "hover" and "overlay" classes but only when I hover on the specific class. Any help would be appreciated!

Thnk in advance!

Comment: Why not do the above things with CSS?

Comment: Hmmm... Yes actually that is a very good point.... How you can sometimes just not see the solutions....

Comment: I think your problem is with the `$("div.overlay")` selector, selecting every `div.overlay` on the page. Try with e.g `$(this).closest("div.overlay");` or something instead.

Comment: Cheers! :-D Thanks for the quick reply, this is awesome!

Comment: Title edit suggestion: "One script to rule them all!"

Comment: Hahaha @PatrickRoberts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS instead. It's also redundant to use `visibility: hidden` alongside `display: none`.

```
div.hover {
    cursor: default;
}
div.hover + div.overlay {
    display: none;
}

div.hover:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
div.hover:hover + div.overlay {
    display: block;
}
```

If you really want your JS to work though, use [`.hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) along with [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.hover").hover(function() {
        $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
        $(this).next("div.overlay").css('display','block');
    }, function() {
        $(this).css('cursor', 'default');
        $(this).next("div.overlay").css('display','none');
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried it with this CSS but that doesn't work, let me see if this javascript works. Thnk for the time&effort.

Comment: Where is `div.overlay` in reference to `div.hover`? Is it a child, a parent, or a sibling?

Comment: Nope, it's just a div below. But of course I can move it. It's currently like this:

<div class="hover"><a href="#">title</a></div>
<div class="overlay">Text </div>

Comment: Ohhh. Ok, I've updated both the CSS and JS solution so that they each do that.

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm now! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$("div.hover").hover(function() {
//On hover operations.
  $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
  $("div.overlay").css('visibility','visible');
  $("div.overlay").css('display','block');

}, function() {
//On hover out operations.
 $(this).css('cursor', 'default');
 $("div.overlay").css('visibility','hidden');
 $("div.overlay").css('display','none');
});
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue of having all of the overlays triggered. They only want the child overlay to be affected.

Comment: Hmmm... For some reason this is still targeting all of the .overlay divs on the whole page.